# JMS in Wildfly 9

Tags: java, queue, jms, wildfly-9

I'm creating a queue in Wildlfy 9, this queue will get about 100 or more Messages per seconds, so  Im trying to find out which is the best way I can send those messages to the queue, in order to get the best performance(no timeouts or delays). Below is what I have so far, I've tested it and it's worked, to be honest I don't know if I should use Queue Session or not. I just need to send the messages and the MDB will process them.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class JMSUtil {

    @Resource(name = "ConnectionFactory")
    private QueueConnectionFactory objQueueFactory;
    @Resource(name = "jms/queue")
    private Queue objQueue;

    private JMSContext context;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        context = objQueueFactory.createContext();
    }

    @Lock(LockType.READ)
    public void sendEvent(String trace) {
        context.createProducer().send(objQueue, trace);
    }
}
```